# Do we need two Dread tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

In response to the comment on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2692/45).  Do we need two `Dread` tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly. As one seems to nurture more discussion than the other, maybe `dread` and `dread-pandemonium`?

Comment: That is the exact suggestion I'd have made. One's in print, one is no longer supported (although still available via Lulu) -- let's give the shorter tag to the former one. Assuming this is consensus, I'll make a point of noting the distinction in the tag wiki tomorrow.

Comment: Makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a third new Dread game. Dread House, which is also by Epidah Ravechol, the author of the Jenga Dread.

Dread house confusingly also uses a jenga tower but is a board game, which shouldn't really feature here?

Comment: Obviously it would be `dread-house` but yes, it shouldn't be here.