# Tags for RPGs that have name conflicts?

Tags: discussion, tags

OK, so I just asked [whether or not I should introduce *Legend* to rpg.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/how-legit-is-it-to-askanswer-some-questions-about-my-favorite-rpg-system-that), and got a favorable response, which is cool.

So, follow-up question. During Rule of Cool’s *Legend*’s alpha stage, Mongoose Publishing changed the name of their *Rune Quest II* to *Legend* due to some copyright problems or something. Rule of Cool’s was definitely the earlier RPG by that name, but Mongoose’s was released first. As it turns out, there is an *even earlier* RPG that, as far as anyone can tell, had the name first.

This isn’t really a problem, since the name is ridiculously generic, except that I’m wondering how I should tag my questions relating to Rule of Cool’s *Legend*, without messing up any potential future questions about Mongoose’s *Legend*.

EDIT: Per C. Ross’s comment, [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/do-we-need-two-dread-tags) is related, and it was decided in that case to give the shorter tag to the system that seemed to get more discussion. However, neither game titled *Legend* has *any* discussion yet, so I'd appreciate suggestions on which, if either, should get the `legend` tag.

Comment: Related: [Do we need two Dread tags?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/440/45)

Comment: @C.Ross: Thanks, I never would have known to search for "dread" on this subject, but I agree it's related. There are some differences, though, so I've updated my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is no Legend tag than first come first served in this case.

When we get questions for the other system we will need to make a distinction, but until that time you're A OK to used [legend](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that sounds pretty good to me (obviously), but I'm going to hold off on accepting because I really want to make sure I've got a sense of the community's opinion on this.

Comment: definitely, always a good idea to wait to accept

Comment: All right, 21 hours and no contrary response. I would have liked more than one upvote (other than mine), but presumably I can't do anything that can't be undone.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds fine. Tagging is pretty laissez-faire, and only needs intervention when a problem becomes manifest. Before then, no worries.

Comment: @KRyan not even mods can do (much) that cannot be undone.

Comment: It doesn't seem like questions for either game are stacking up and vying for the tag, however it might be nice if a redirection or something were in the Legend tag to indicate that the Mongoose product can be found under tag X, or split them into Legend-OGL and Legend-RQ so a tag search would present a clear option.

Comment: @Runeslinger So far as I know, there are *zero* questions for Mongoose's Legend. If I'm wrong about that, some kind of separation might be warranted.